Questions about Corollary 5.23 of AG1: Schemes by Görtz & Wedhorn
In the book, a theorem is stated with a clear demonstration. I simply write the points of the theorem that interest me (in the following, $k$ is any field) :

Theorem 5.22. Let $X$ be an irreducible $k$-scheme locally of finite type (...).

Let $x \in X$ be any closed point. Then $\dim \mathcal O_{X,x} = \dim X$.
Let $f : Y \to X$ be a morphism of $k$-schemes locally of finite type with finite fibers. Then $\dim Y \leq \dim X$.


Just then it is written (without a proof) :

Corollary 5.23. Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme locally of finite type and let $x \in X$ be a closed point. Then $\dim \mathcal O_{X,x} = \sup_Z \dim Z$ where $Z$ runs through the (finitely many) irreducible components of $X$ containing $x$.

I try to demonstrate this corollary without much success.
- First question : why $x$ belongs to finitely many irreducible components of $X$ ? Of course if $X$ is of finite type, it is straightforward.
- Second question : if $Z$ is an irreducible component containing $x$, we can consider $Z$ as an integral $k$-scheme locally of finite type giving it the reduced structure. Then by Theorem 5.22 and by the surjective morphism $\mathcal O_{X,x} \to \mathcal O_{Z,x}$, we have $\dim \mathcal O_{X,x} \geq \dim Z = \dim \mathcal O_{Z,x}$. By taking the supremum : $\dim \mathcal O_{X,x} \geq \sup_Z \dim Z$, but I’m not able to demonstrate the reverse inequality. Do you have an idea? Thank you.


Let $U \subset X$ be an open noetherian neighbourhood of $x$. Clearly every irreducible component of $X$ which contains $x$ intersects $U$. But as $U$ is noetherian, it has only finitely many irreducible components.
Each irreducible component $Z$ which contains $x$ corresponds to a minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $\mathcal O_{X,x}$, and every maximal chain of prime ideals in $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ has to end in a minimal prime $\mathfrak p$. The corresponding sequence of closed subsets is then contained in $Z$.


Thank you for that answer. My question was answered almost at the same time. Your answer is much more concise and I think it deserves to be accepted for that reason (in addition to being perfectly clear). There is a very light typo that has little importance, but perhaps it should eplace "correspond to the minimal prime ideal minimal(...)" in "correspond to one of the minimal prime ideals (...)"
